# Using PHP to output JSON data, and I get "white screen of death" when too many rows being called

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using PHP files to output JSON data from a MySQL database. My code works just fine when I'm only pulling about 50 rows, however my database contains over 12,000 rows. Does anyone know how I might go about pulling more data without my server returning the "White screen of death"? Lol. My current code is below:

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from customer limit 50", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['customerfname'] = $row['customerfname'];
        $row_array['customerlname'] = $row['customerlname'];
        $row_array['customeremail'] = $row['customeremail'];
        $row_array['customerphone'] = $row['customerphone'];
        $row_array['customercity'] = $row['customercity'];
        $row_array['customeraddress'] = $row['customeraddress'];
        $row_array['lastupdate'] = $row['lastupdate'];
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    //Close the database connection
    fclose($db);

?>
```

Comment: It is probable, although highly unlikely, that your 12,000 rows are crossing the 8 MB data limit set by default for `$_POST`. Try gradually increasing the `limit` to a thousand, then a couple of thousand to see where it breaks.
PS: `mysql_*` days are numbered. Try and use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: There is also a probability that your code is exhausting PHP's memory limit. Try using `var_dump(memory_get_usage());` inside while to debug how much memory it is consuming.

Comment: @BasitSaeed Thank you! Just fixed it :) Follow up question: I'm using this as a backend for an iOS app; would you happen to know how I could make the load time of all this data quicker? Right now it takes my app a good 8 seconds to cue up all of the information...

Comment: My pleasure! :) How'd you solve it, though? Sure, why don't you start a chat session or perhaps a different question as discussing this here would be out of scope of this question.

Comment: @BasitSaeed I don't have the ability to create a new room yet, lol :( Invite me to chat? Also: I fixed it by narrowing down my rows; it appears as though I had an error at row 7,995 lol :/

Comment: i've created a room. Here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60028/chat-with-brittany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first 50 rows are coming well, the problem is probably with the data...
i think a malicious single quote or something

You can try different sets of data by using limit like so.
for example if you want to check next 50 and skip first 50 with limit

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from customer limit 50, 50", $db);
```

i think you should try in sets of 1 to 50 , 50 to 100 and then narrow down to next 10 and find out which set and then which row / record is giving problem and then search out a solution for json encoding the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

You could output json data according to GET/POST parameter, by paginating the results in your sql table. E.g., if you want the rows from 50th to 100th, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    // Get the page we are interested in
    $page = $_REQUEST['page']; // E.g. 1

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT ".(50*$page).",50");

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    // free result set
    $result->close();

    //Close the database connection
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```